# Toggle (show/hide) element with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

By using this method I can show/hide an element by using 2 buttons:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function showStuff(id) {
        document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
}
function hideStuff(id) {
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
}
</script>

<input type="button" onClick="hideStuff('themes')" value="Hide">
<input type="button" onClick="showStuff('themes')" value="Show">
<div id="themes" style="display:block">
    <h3>Stuff</h3>
</div>
```

Is there a method to use a single button?? Maybe if & else?

Comment: Use jQuery's toggle and have fun http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Comment: Check `.style.display`'s value _first_, then set its value accordingly. If it's hidden, show it. If it's shown, hide it.

Comment: ca'nt be that hard, something like : `style.display = style.display == 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've already answered your question...the use of `if`/`else`:

```
function toggle(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);

    if (element) {
        var display = element.style.display;

        if (display == "none") {
            element.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            element.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

This won't be completely foolproof, in case you are hiding/showing `inline` or `inline-block` elements, *or* if you are using non-default values for `display` on elements...such as setting a div's `display` to "inline" (for whatever reason) and then trying to use this function

Answer (score 0):

Yes if/else will work

```
function toggle(id){
    var elem = document.getElementById(id);
    if(elem.style.display == 'block'){
        elem.style.display == 'none'
    } else if(elem.style.display == 'none'){
        elem.style.display == 'block'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean something like this:

```
 function toggle(id){
var elem = document.getElementById(id);
if(elem.style.display == "block"){
    elem.style.display="none";
} else {
    elem.style.display="block";
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate solution. Instead of using `document.getElementById`, you can also use **`document.querySelector`** which returns the **first Element** within the document that matches the specified selector, or group of selectors.

Solution Code:

```
function toggleShow() {
    var elem = document.querySelector(id);
    if(elem.style.display == 'inline-block'){
      elem.style.display="none";
    }
    else {
      elem.style.display = "inline-block";
    }
  }
```