# using javascript to change display

Tags: javascript, html, css

So I looked at other questions and I found an answer that was chosen on this link:

[Toggle (show/hide) element with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921042/toggle-show-hide-element-with-javascript)

This below was the following function that works in the answer to change the display.

```
function toggle(id) {
var element = document.getElementById(id);

  if (element) {
    var display = element.style.display;

    if (display == "none") {
        element.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        element.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}
```

I tried that in my code, but it's not working. I've attached a link to the JSFiddle at the end or this post.

I have a parent **div** with the **id** of #activities. It contains multiple children, but the important ones are the **li**,**p**, and **div** which has an id as #suggestion_input. Below is the HTML.

**HTML**

```
<div id="activities" class="info_container">
        <h1>Our Activities</h1>
        <div class="contain">
            <ul>  
                <li>Activity 1</li>
                <li>Activity 2</li>
                <li>Activity 3 </li>
                <li>Activity 4 </li>
                <li>Activity 5</li>
                <li>Activity 6 </li>
                <li>Activity 7</li>
                <li>Your Suggestions</li>
            </ul>
            <p> 
                Bacon ipsum dolor sit amet ribeye tenderloin meatball, chuck andouille beef ribs jerky ...
            </p>
            <div id="suggestion_input">
                <label for="name" >Your Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
                <label for="suggestions">Suggestions</label>
                <textarea id="suggestions" name="suggestions" rows="39"></textarea>
            </div>
```

When the user clicks the last **li** in the ul called "Your Suggestions", then the **p** will have display set to none and the #suggestion_input will have display of inline-block. Currently, their css is set to inline-block and none respectively.

**CSS**

```
 #activities p{
 display:inline-block;
 width:500px;
 vertical-align:top;
 margin-top:20px;
 margin-left:20px;
 background:#FFFDA1;
 }

 #suggestion_input{
 display:none;
 margin-left:150px;
 vertical-align:top;
 margin-top:20px;
 text-align:center;
  }
```

And then this is my javascript which I think reflects the answer in the link except that it isn't a function.

**Javascript** - This code is part of an addEventListener. Event is a "click".

```
 if(e.target.innerText === 'Your Suggestions'){

            var para = document.getElementById('activities').querySelector('p');
            var display = para.style.display;
            /* if you uncomment this, then the following code will work
            outside of the if display == 'inline-block' condition

            para.style.display = 'none';
            suggestion_input.style.display = 'inline-block';

            */

            if(display == 'inline-block'){
                // This code will not work
                para.style.display = 'none';
                suggestion_input.style.display = 'inline-block';
                console.log('works');
            }
        }else{
            if(display == 'none'){
                display = "inline-block";
            }
        }
    }
```

When I click, nothing happens. Is the error because of the condition in the if statement of "display == 'none'" ?

Here is the JSfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/a4t7w/1/

Comment: console.log(display) just before the if could give you (and us) a clue. BTW. I've not found any target with "Your suggestions" in the piece of html... post that part also.

Comment: I took a screenshot but to add images it seems that it needs to be on a server or website so I can reference it by url. I'm using chrome, and the result returned nothing back but a reference to the js doc. so something like this -->  whitespace          js playpen.js:27  --- 27 is the line where I put the console.log(display)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so to start, part of your problem is with the understanding that `para.style.display` equals `inline-block` like is set in your style sheet.  Unfortunately in this usage Javascript is accessing your **inline styles** as defined with the element itself and **not** what you are defining with external CSS.

So this statement: `if(display == 'inline-block')` never returns `true` because `display` is actually set to `""`.  If you aren't already, get familiar with [Firebug for Firefox](https://getfirebug.com/).  It does wonders for helping debug this kind of stuff.

Another thing is here: `if(e.target.innerText === 'Your Suggestions')`.  Instead of `innerText` you should use `innerHTML` or `textContent`.  The `innerText` property is an IE thing.

Now, to solve your problem!  I see you are attaching the click event to the `<div>` element that holds your `<ul>` element.  If you only need this click event you function on your "Suggestions" `<li>` then I would recommend you isolate that particular element when attaching your listener.

Change your HTML and JS:

```
<li id="suggestionToggle">Your Suggestions</li>
...
document.getElementById('suggestionToggle').addEventListener("click",function(e) ...
```

Next you can rewrite your Javascript to test for the presence of `""` or `inline-block` when setting your styles on the `<p>` element.  Here's an updated version of your code:

```
document.getElementById('activities').addEventListener("click",function(e)
{
    var suggestion_input = document.getElementById('suggestion_input');
    var para = document.getElementById('activities').querySelector('p');
    var light_green = document.getElementById('activities').querySelector('.light_green');      


if(light_green){
    light_green.style.backgroundColor="red";
    light_green.className = "";
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#0DFFB9';
    e.target.className = 'light_green';
} else {
    e.target.style.backgroundColor = '#0DFFB9';
    e.target.className = 'light_green';
}

if(e.target.innerHTML == 'Your Suggestions') {       
    var display = para.style.display;           

    if(display == 'inline-block' || display == "") {
        // This code will not work ** It will now! **
        para.style.display = 'none';
        suggestion_input.style.display = 'inline-block';
    } else {
        if(display != "inline-block") {
            para.style.display = "inline-block";
            suggestion_input.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
} else {        
    para.style.display = "inline-block";
    suggestion_input.style.display = "none";
}
```

});

JS Fiddle to see the toggle in action is here: http://jsfiddle.net/RyUz5/8/

Hope that helps!

**EDIT:** Enabled proper toggling that I accidentally stripped out as noted by yancie.

Comment: wow thanks for the clear explanation! Sorry for the change in accepted answers.

Comment: @user3029001 I've updated this answer to fix the toggling of the suggestion form when clicking on an activity.

Answer (score 5):

There is a couple of error in your js , I listed them in the comment , 4 in totoal

```
document.getElementById('activities').addEventListener("click",function(e){

    // SKIP THIS CODE, THE ERROR LIES BELOW

        // 1. put the var outside of the if/else 
        var para = document.getElementById('activities').querySelector('p');
        var display = para.style.display;

        // THIS WAS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS           
        if(e.target.innerText === 'Your Suggestions'){

            if(display = 'inline-block'){   // 2. it should be "=" instead of "=="
                para.style.display = 'none';
                suggestion_input.style.display = 'inline-block';
                console.log('works');
            }
        }else{
            if(display = 'none'){
                suggestion_input.style.display = 'none';    // 3. add in suggestion display none
                para.style.display = 'inline-block';    // 4. "para.style.display" instead of "display"
            }
        }
    } 
});
```

A working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/a4t7w/7/

So now when you click suggestion , the from show up, than if you click the activity, the paragraph come back in, from disappear

Comment: wow. I'm embarrassed. I've been staring at the code for so long my mind just glazed over those errors. Sorry for my recklessness and wasting your guys' time

Comment: wait, but isn't = an assignment operator? Oh well, the code works. So why wouldn't the condition (display == 'inline-block') work?

Comment: @Crackertastic Explained it :) But I believe his answer twisted your original code a little, it was suppose to "click suggestion -> from show up" | than "click activity -> activity show up" , but it's changed to toggle the form by clicking suggestion, and show the last activity been viewed, a little weird if you ask me

Comment: @yancie +1 to you!  Thanks for pointing that out.  I edited my answer to toggle the form suggestion form off when clicking an activity.

Answer (score 1):

Read this line carefully:

```
/* 
if you uncomment this, then the following code will work
 outside of the if display == 'inline-block' condition

para.style.display = 'none';
suggestion_input.style.display = 'inline-block';

*/
```

now all you have to do is uncomment this line:

```
para.style.display = 'none';
suggestion_input.style.display = 'inline-block';
```

Comment: I took that comment in the code as he means that the problem/error is not _inside_ the if, but in the if itself. Don't you think it makes more sense? @DOMUSNETWORK

Comment: miguel_svq is correct. I just added the code inside the first if statement to check if the code itself is working. However, the code does not work in the second if statement.And even when I uncommented, if I wanted to reshow the paragraph when I click on other links, the code doesn't work again for the if statement. JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a4t7w/6/